# Parsing S-expressions with arbitrary delimiters in LISP

Tags: xml, lisp, common-lisp, context-free-grammar, s-expression

(I'm new enough to Lisp not to know how to do this, but familiar enough to know there just *must* be a simple way.)

I was intrigued by an article that I read recently which advocated storing log files as Lisp-style S-expressions, so that the log files could be turned into a DSL easily. This got me thinking about similar grammars for other DSLs, but I've run into a snag.

Parsing s-expressions where the delimiters are parentheses is easy

```
"(my-function foo bar)"
```

can be read from a file/stream and evaluated trivially.

And if XML is really just an S-expression, shouldn't there be an easy way to transform something as simple as

```
<function>foo bar etc-1 etc-2</function>
```

into

```
(function foo bar etc-1 etc-2)
```

I can fake this behavior with string manipulation techniques (heck, a regex could take care of this, really). But that seems like Lisp blasphemy - these are just S-expressions! The same applies for the Lisp-based versions of lex/yacc - I can see the need for more complex syntax, but really, this is just Lisp syntax disguised in a less efficient manner.

This should, in theory, extend beyond XML, to any context-free grammar that is a homomorphism of the Lisp grammar. (I know that Lisp is supposedly not perfectly defined by a context-free grammar as simple as the S-expression, but obviously the latter is a strict subset of the former, so my statement still stands).

**So, in short:** Is there a simple way to define the syntax for a context-free grammar homomorphic to S-expressions (like XML, for example) and parse that grammar within Lisp (or a Lisp-based DSL)?

Comment: I thought it was implied, but maybe it wasn't clear since I didn't phrase it as a question. Edited to clarify it (at the end).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that by implementing "reader macros" in lisp that will take your XML and convert them to S-expr. Once in S-expr everything is  simple in LISP world.

Ex: http://www.agentsheets.com/lisp/XMLisp/

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to parse XML with [reader macros](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_set_ma.htm#set-macro-character) but I'm not aware of anyone having done so.

[S-XML](http://common-lisp.net/project/s-xml/) is a simple XML parser and builder, but if I remember it doesn't use reader macros.

Part of the reason reader macros haven't been used to solve this problem conclusively is that XML is in fact, despite initial appearances, [really complicated](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/xml/s-exp_vs_XML).